# Add POS tags as attribute to xml element

Tags: python, xml, pos-tagger

I would like to add the output of a parts-of-speech tagger to an existing xml file with the POS-tags as attribute value pairs to the existing word element:

```
house/N + <w>house</w> --> <w pos="N">house</w>
```

I thought I could give unique IDs to the words, match those and then add the POS-tag to the existing xml file, so I designed the following function in Python:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def add_postags(POSfile, xmlfile):
    """
    Function that takes two arguments (POSfile, xmlfile).
    If the value of the word <w>'s attribute 'id' in the POSfile matches
    the value of 'id' in the existing xml file,
    it adds the pos tags that are stored as attribute-value pairs in (POSfile)
    to the xml file and writes this to a new document 'xmlPOS'.
    """

    treePOS = ET.parse(POSfile)
    rootPOS = treePOS.getroot()
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
    root = tree.getroot()


    for w in rootPOS.iter('w'):
        idPOS = w.get('id')

    for w in root.iter('w'):
        idxml = w.get('id')

    for w in rootPOS.iter('w'):
        POSval = w.get('pos')

    if idPOS == idxml:        
        w.set('pos', POSval)

    tree.write('xmlPOS.xml')

    return xmlPOS
```

For this to work I'd have to convert the tagger output 'house/N' to an xml format:

```
<w id="1" pos="N">house</w>
```

But even if I do so and then import the above module in Python, I seem to be unable to add the POS tags to the existing xml file (which contains more editorial markup of course than the above example). Perhaps I should use XSLT instead of this Python xml parser? I'm not very familiar with XSLTs yet, so I thought I'd try this in Python first.

Any comments or suggestions will be much appreciated: thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `set` method is the appropriate way to set attributes in ElementTree, and I just tested that it works when applied to an XML file read from disk.

I wonder if your problem is algorithmic--- the algorithm you wrote doesn't look like it does what you want.  The `idPOS`, `idxml`, and `POSval` are going to be equal to the *last* matching values in each file and `w` is going to be equal to the last `<w>` tag.  It can only change one word, the last one.  If you're going to be setting part of speech attributes in bulk, perhaps you want something more like the following (you may need to tweak the it if I've made some wrong assumptions about how `POSfile` is structured):

```
# load all "pos" attributes into a dictionary for fast lookup
posDict = {}
for w in rootPOS.iter("w"):
    if w.get("pos") is not None:
        posDict[w.text] = w.get("pos")

# if we see any matching words in the xmlfile, set their "pos" attrbute
for w in root.iter("w"):
    if w.text in posDict:
        w.set("pos", posDict[w.text])
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! This seems to be working on my simplified test file at least. Now I'll try and make it work for the actual files with more elements and attributes it will need to skip over. Your code snippet is a big help: very much appreciated!

Comment: Alright, I now find it works for the test file only because all words in this small sample file are unique. In the actual text, however, this is not the case, which is why I gave the words unique IDs in the first place so I could match them. E.g. the word 'play' in English will sometimes have the POS-tag  "N(oun)" and sometimes the POS-tag "V(erb)" depending on the context, so if I store them in a dictionary like you suggest, this unique context is lost, isn't it? That's why I thought I should add the unique IDs, but perhaps there's a way of building that into it?

Comment: To identify part of speech by context would require natural language processing, which would be a considerably more complex algorithm than we've been talking about.  Probably the simplest approach that would be maybe 90% accurate (rough numbers) is to do an n-gram analysis, where you look for pairs of words and map them to pairs of parts of speech.  For instance, "children play" will always be noun-verb.  Not only does that increase the complexity of the algorthm, but the dataset will need to be much bigger because there are a lot more two-word combinations to search for than single words.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I was not clear: the NLP task's been done, the pos-tags are there. I've use a Memory-Based Tagger (Generator) and manually corrected the resulting files. The only thing I need now is to add those pos-tags to the xml-file where the text originally came from.

Comment: You'd need to say more about how the NLP results are presented for use.  How are the two files structured and how, in pseudocode, do you want to perform the tagging?

Answer (score 0):

I've performed the tagging, but I need to write te output into the xml file. The tagger output looks like this:

```
The/DET house/N is/V big/ADJ ./PUNC
```

The xml file from which the text came will look like this:

```
<s>
 <w>The</w>
 <w>house</w>
 <w>is</w>
 <w>big</w>
 <w>.</w>
</s>
```

Now I would like to add the pos-tags as attribute-value pairs to the xml elements:

```
<s>
 <w pos="DET">The</w>
 <w pos="N">house</w>
 <w pos="V">is</w>
 <w pos="ADJ">big</w>
 <w pos="PUNC">.</w>
</s>
```

I hope this sample in English makes it clear (I'm actually working on historical Welsh).

Answer (score 0):

I have now managed to do something like this with ElementTree:

```
import sys
import os
import re
import tree

def xmldump(file_name, xmldump):

    """
    Function takes one argument (file_name), and returns a list
    containing (for every sentence) a list of word-pos pairs
    It then converts this output to xml.
    """

text = ' '.join(open(file_name).readlines())

#split the text into sentences
sentences = re.split("\.\/PUNC", text)

xmlcorpus = []

#convert sentences to xml    
for s in sentences:
    t = tree.xml(s)
    xmlcorpus.append(t)

#write xmlcorpus to new file
with open(xmldump, 'w') as f:
    for sent in xmlcorpus:
        f.write(sent)

return xmldump
```

This sort of works, although there are now 'chink' and 'chunk' elements automatically generated by the ElementTree 'tree' module that I can't get rid of somehow.